# Break if any key is pressed c++

Tags: c++

I want to break out of a while loop if the User pressed any key during a Sleep(miliseconds), as in stop if any key is pressed during those miliseconds. How do I do that?
The loop looks like this:

```
while (1)
{
    r = rand() % 5501 + 1000;
    Sleep(r);
    cout << "NOW!\n";
    t = clock() / 1000;
    system("pause");
    if (clock() / 1000 < t + 1)
    {
        cnt++;
        cout << "Aaaaand...\n";
    }
    else break;
}
```

Platform: Windows

Comment: Which platform are you on?

Comment: It depends on the capabilities of your terminal and operating system. There's no C++ language function for that.

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449324/how-to-simulate-press-any-key-to-continue

Comment: Like that but in an if, not waiting

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157295/interrupt-sleep-function is a good start to understand how to sleep could be interrupted

Comment: Instead of awaiting user input, I want to keep it as a condition for breaking out of the while loop

Comment: Neither of these two

Comment: Why don't you use of thread? One thread wait for user input and start another which perform other part when user press a key? (I know it's not the question)

Comment: You should edit question and add the platform tag (Windows, Linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `kbhit()`. Try this:

```
bool exit = false;
while(!exit){
    if(kbhit())
         exit = true;
}
```

This'll work if you're working with windows. If you are with linux you can also copy paste kbhit.h y kbhit.cpp from http://linux-sxs.org/programming/kbhit.html and add it to your project.

Answer (score 3):

There is no C++ language solution to do this.

You will have to find a platform specific function which waits until there is input available with a timeout.  Call that function instead of `Sleep` (which is also not a C++ function).  On return from that function check the return code to see if it returned because there is input available (user pressed a key), or timed out (user didn't press a key).